# How to get GSON & Retrofit to serialize and map an array from a JSON response into a String?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, sugarorm

I am making an API request which returns some array values. I need to serialize these array values so that I can assign them to their corresponding class attributes (which are String types).

Now I know how to use GSON to serialize and deserialize lists, but with Retrofit the mapping is done automatically. This means that if my attribute is of type String, the API call returns the error "Expected a String but received an Array instead". How do I get around this so that I can receive them as arrays without failure, and them store them as strings subsequently?

My API Response:

```
{
"utterances": [{
        "langs": ["eng", "afr", "xho", "zul"],
        "utts": [
            "Have you been here before?",
            "Was u al hier gewees?",
            "Ingaba wakhe weza apha ngaphambili?",
            "Ingabe uke weza lapha ngaphambilini?"
        ],
        "responses": [
            ["Yes", "No"],
            ["Ja", "Nee"],
            ["Ewe", "Hayi"],
            ["Yebo", "Cha"]
        ]
    },
    {
        "langs": ["eng", "afr", "xho", "zul"],
        "utts": [
            "How are you?",
            "Hoe gaan dit met jou?",
            "unjani?",
            "unjani?"
        ],
        "responses": [
            ["Good", "Bad"],
            ["Goed", "sleg"],
            ["ezilungileyo", "ezimbi"],
            ["kuhle", "kubi"]
        ]
    }
]
}
```

My UtteranceResponse class:

```
class UtteranceResponse {

@SerializedName("status")
var status: String? = null

@SerializedName("count")
var count: Int = 0

@SerializedName("utterances")
var utterances: ArrayList<Utterance>? = null
}
```

My Utterance class:

```
class Utterance: SugarRecord {

@SerializedName ("langs")
var langs: String? = null

@SerializedName ("utts")
var utterances_text: String? = null

var utterances_tts: String? = null

@SerializedName ("responses")
var responses_text: String? = null

constructor(){

}
}
```

And finally the calling function:

```
    fun getUtterancesFromWebservice (){
    val apiService = ApiInterface.create()
    val call = apiService.getUtteranceDetails()

    call.enqueue(object: Callback<UtteranceResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UtteranceResponse>, response: retrofit2.Response<UtteranceResponse>?) {
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.body()?.utterances != null){
                    var list: List<Utterance> = response.body()?.utterances!!
                    val utterances: Utterance = list[0]
                    //storeUtterancesFromList(list)
                } else {
                    Log.d ("Response:", response.body().toString())
                }
            }else{
                Log.d ("responseResult", "NULL")
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UtteranceResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("SHIT", t.toString())

        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE**
My API Interface as well:

```
@GET("bins/1ahazo")
abstract fun getUtteranceDetails():Call<UtteranceResponse>

    companion object Factory {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/"
        fun create(): ApiInterface {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had originally. I think I erased it by mistake.

Comment: Fixed, it was a typo.

Comment: 2am here. And you do not have an option to change the class `Utterance`?

Comment: 1 hour ahead. Do you mean with regards to the typo? I fixed that. Unless I'm not understanding your question...

Comment: I mean `var responses_text: String? = null`, you cannot change that to be an array of `Utterances`?

Comment: I could, but I dont think that would solve my issue. There is still an array to store of the Utterance in its 4 different languages. I could store it as an object (let's say an Utt object), but then don't I need an array of said objects?

Comment: please share the code of the ApiInterface

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: You have have problem in the ApiInterface. check the answer

Comment: your data model is wrong- you need more arrays! Use a online json to pojo convertor. If you use kotlin consider using `data class`, these override `hashcode()` and `equals()` automatically.

Comment: OK. I was avoiding arrays because I wasn't able to store them. Or so I thought. And it seems I can't use data class's with sugar record, so my intention has been to switch over to Room. Perhaps its time.

Comment: Sure, your outer class is correct (if status and count exist in the outer top level json), but `Utterances` is not - also the below answer is wrong, you will only return `Call<UtteranceResponse>` - a single object which contains the rest of the data model.

Comment: As said few times:  deserialize it as an array if it is an array in the response. Then you can stringify it. But maybe you want to implement some JsonDeserializer  / TypeAdapter..

Answer (score 0):

You are returning single object not list. Change `Call<UtteranceResponse>` in ApiInterface to

```
Call<List<Utterance>>
```

and for converting list to string [list to string and string to list](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/convert-list-array)

```
class Utterance: SugarRecord {

@SerializedName ("langs")
var langs: List<String?>? = null 

@SerializedName ("utts")
var utterances_text: String? = null

var utterances_tts: List<String?>? = null

@SerializedName ("responses")
var responses_tex:List<List<String?>?>? = null;

constructor(){

 }
}
```

Comment: Should it not rather be Call<List<Utterance>> as the list is of 'Utterance' and not 'UtteranceResponse' ?

Comment: The response JSON has a list of `Utterances` not `UtteranceResponses`. Or am I missing something? Response JSON is the response.

Comment: This is my confusion as well. If I assume the question in my comment above is correct, I've done this and get an error which I've had when trying something similar before: `call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Utterance>>` gives me an error: `Type mismatch: Required Callback<List<Utterance>!>!`. and the 'Found' part is just empty.

Comment: Also, I understand how to do the conversions mentioned in your link. My issue is that retrofit does the mapping automatically. So if the attribute for utterance_text is a string type, it expects a string value in the json. If its an array (which it is in this case), there is a failure. I don't have the chance between the call being made and this failure occurring to convert the array to String.

Comment: Your model class also need to be fixed as you are returning array in the json response from the service while you have declare it as string inside  you model class.

Comment: @Glenncito hops it helps now.